# Issues with Youtube-To MP3

Tags: 14.04, youtube, mp3

When using Ubuntu Software Center and Apt-Get to install Youtube to MP3 I am receiveing these errors:

```
the following packages have unmet dependencies:

youtube-to-mp3: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
                Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Depends: libqt4-declarative (>= 4:4.7.0~rc1) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.6.1) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Depends: libav-tools (>= 4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libmp3lame0 (>= 3.99.3+repack1-1) but 3.99.5+repack1-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

This package is either not available, or is not going to be installed for some other reason. You will have to run `apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53` to see if there is an error specific to that package, for why it is not going to be installed. This may lead you to further errors. You will have to trace these errors through until you find and resolve whatever the conflict is, or resolve to not install the app, because it conflicts with something else you do need.